# how to set the interpreter of wxpython for eclipse once for all

Tags: eclipse, macos, python-2.7, wxpython

I've Eclipse, python 2.7, wxpython 2.8, and OSx 10.5.8
I would like wxpython is included correctly in my eclipse environment, to have not all the wxpython commands underlined as errors.

I've imported in the PYTHONPATH, via preferences, the correct path of the wx library. Once I import them manually in the Eclipse, save settings, then it works.

But if i close Eclipse, and open it again, even if the interpreter have its own path of wxpython, it seems it's not recognized, and I've no autocomplete, no documentation. I need to remove and add again the same path to make everything work. It still happen after months. I guess it maybe a problem of macosx eclipse.

Do you know why?
Do you agree?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always go to Preferences / PyDev / Interpreter - Python. Then add a new interpreter, and just click Add and Apply. Wait until everything is parsed, this takes a while. Then click OK.

Change the interpreter from "Default" to your newly set-up interpreter.

Check if correct interpreter is set for your project. Right-click the project / Properties / PyDev - Interpreter/Grammar. New projects should get this by default.